# No Idea why : The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm new to jersey and web services and I'm try to run a simple RESTful web service. I followed http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/ but my project doesn't use maven and I download the jersey.1.17.1.jar and include it to my project path.

When I want to call the service on `http://localhost:8080/sycotext/rest/service/SOMETEXT` I get this error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet sycoText-servlet threw exception
```

this is the stack trace :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet sycoText-servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1010)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1618)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1576)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1010)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1618)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1576)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

here is my code :

```
package ir.sycotech.text.server.service;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/service")
public class SycoTextService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
   }
```

and here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sycoText-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ir.sycotech.text.server.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sycoText-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have specified my packagename correctly in the web.xml file and I don't know why I got this error, I will be really appreciate if anyone knows what is the problem

Comment: Probably init() method is missing.

Comment: can you explain it more ?

Comment: Clean Apache tomcat will work...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error:

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

means that Jersey can't find service classes. That can be caused by a wrongly named package for the `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` parameter or if the package name is correct but it does not contain resource classes (people sometimes forget to add the `@Path` annotation on the class).

But I can't find anything wrong with your setup. So this should work!

Check that your application deployed correctly and that your `WEB-INF/classes` folder actually contains your class with the proper folder path for the package.

Do a full clean and rebuild then try again.

Comment: thanks a lot i found the problem, the problem was in war file. i use intelliJ idea 13 and it's artifacts to generate the war file and it just do it in wrong manner and i don't know why it put the packages in the root folder of war file :|

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me crazy. In my case, I was missing the @Path before the class. I had Paths for the methods but the general Path was missing and I had the same error in console

Comment: The same problem @VahidHaratian said also occurs in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 Ultimate version. The folder classes is generated in the root folder, not inside WEB-INF. My project is a Maven one, I do not know if it occurs with non-Maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

I do not no the actual problem you are facing.
You can dwonload an example https://github.com/kdmalviyan/RestWithJerseyExample.git 
you have to take following actions after downloading:
1. mvn clean install
2. deploy war to your server
3. access "JerseyExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/hello/hello Kuldeep Singh" on your server

You will get Output like: Jersey say : hello Kuldeep Singh

I suggest you to follow exact steps without any change anything first. If you get correct result then you can modify according to your need. Please make sure if you are renaming package, rename package in web.xml too.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem using Grizzly with jersey.

When you fire up a a Grizzly container you have to pass in a map telling Grizzly where to find your resources.  If you created your project from an archetype like I did or just moved some things around you also have to update this value which is easy to overlook.

```
    final static String YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_GOES_HERE = "where.ever.your.resource.package.happens.to.be"

    final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
            YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_GOES_HERE);

    System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
    SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(BASE_URI, initParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, as well. There were two things that I did to get it to work, with the first being unrelated to this problem.

First, I'm using jersey 1.19. However, I didn't realize there was a file named 
`javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` on the server. This file was added two years ago and, IIRC, works in conjunction with jersey 2.x but not 1.x. I effectively removed the file (renamed it with *.bak* as its extension).

Second, I created a JAR file in Eclipse for the web service. I did not use Maven or Ant or anything like that. Just a simple export. Now, the error can mean there is nothing in your code that references jersey. But I wrote a simple test class and everything should be working, I thought. Turns out the export wasn't creating the JAR file properly. I opened the JAR and the class was empty. No wonder it was generating this error! I exported once more and instead of checkmarking `Export generated class files and resources`, I checkmarked `Export all output folders for checked projects`. I also have multiple packages in this one project so that could be related to why the export wasn't functioning properly. Once I did that, it worked!

I tried the export again but, this time, I checkmarked `Export generated class files and resources` and selected every resource in the project. What was different from last time was I selected `.settings`. Last time, `.settings` wasn't selected. Again, this worked, too!

I hope this helps someone out there with a similar problem. Sometimes, it's just something as stupid as confirming your JAR file is correct. I use [java decompiler](https://github.com/java-decompiler) to inspect the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar problem. Please check your initialization process whether you have registered the api class properly.

In your case, the initialization class is ir.sycotech.text.server.service

You need to register all api class in service.

Here is my example:

I will hit the error if the following classes are not registered, (         register(CtoFService.class);
            register(FtoCService.class);
            register(TriggerCmd.class);)

```
    *<init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>my.mimos.hcserver.init.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>*



 @ApplicationPath("/HCRestServer/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
    public MyApplication() {
        System.out.println("******Started!*****");
        register(CtoFService.class);
        register(FtoCService.class);
        register(TriggerCmd.class);
        register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
        System.out.println("******Done registration!*****");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your package "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" is registered correctly in Web.xml ... Good Luck !!

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <servletclass>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.rest.service</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>         
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to use HttpServerFactory, you must pass a PackagesResourceConfig.

Example:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.package");
HttpServerFactory.create(getBaseURI(), rc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which I solved by specifying BOTH the classes package AND removing *load-on-startup* altogether, i.e.:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet-name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> -->
</servlet>
```

I guess because I had more than one servlet under the same package and Jersey coudn't pick the "root" one to be loaded on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, none of the above answers worked for me. They made me double check every step and package name, though. As Bogdan said, there were no compiled classes inside the `target/classes/` folder.

> Check that your application deployed correctly and that your WEB-INF/classes folder actually contains your class with the proper folder path for the package.

My solution was just cleaning the project and compiling different. Instead of just going for `mvn war:war` I did:

`$ mvn clean:clean
$ mvn compile
$ mvn war:war`

Then it compiled fine and the OP error disappeared.